# Ionic 4 Angular 8 Razorpay Payment Gateway integration error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, razorpay

Ionic 4 Angular 8 Razorpay integration error :

> Alert {"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"The id provided does not exist"} (Error 3)

While I try to payment from ionic app in android, I am getting an above issue.

Please check my code below

```js
payWithRazor() {
    var options = {
      description: 'First order for customer.',
      image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
      currency: 'INR',
      key: 'rzp_test_1DP5mmOlF5G5ag',
      order_id: 'order_7HtFNLS98dSj8x',
      amount: '5000',
      name: 'foo',
      prefill: {
        email: 'pranav@razorpay.com',
        contact: '8879524924',
        name: 'Pranav Gupta'
      },
      theme: {
        color: '#F37254'
      }
    }

    var successCallback = function(success) {
      alert('payment_id: ' + success.razorpay_payment_id)
      var orderId = success.razorpay_order_id
      var signature = success.razorpay_signature
    }

    var cancelCallback = function(error) {
      alert(error.description + ' (Error '+error.code+')')
    }

    RazorpayCheckout.on('payment.success', successCallback);
    RazorpayCheckout.on('payment.cancel', cancelCallback);
    RazorpayCheckout.open(options);
  }
```

Comment: have you install rozerpay cordova plugin?

Comment: check Razorpay API document for this error.

Comment: yes I have installed razorpay cordova plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
**Angular app Payment getway using        
capacitor- for angulr mobile APK**

 Set the app with capacitor 
npm i @capacitor/ios @capacitor/android
npx cap add android
Npx sync
 npx cap open 


 Plunning install using – force 
Url -  https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/capacitor-integration/build-integration/#12-install-razorpay-capacitor-plugin

npm i https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-capacitor.git – force

Go to (CRTL+P) search -  proguard-rules.pro

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn com.razorpay.**
-keep class com.razorpay.** {*;}

-optimizations !method/inlining/*

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public void onPayment*(...);
}


Go to (CRTL+P) search -  MainActivity.java
    
    package com.akhi.app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.ionicframework.capacitor.Checkout;


public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
     @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    registerPlugin(Checkout.class);
  }
}





Go to (CRTL+P) search -  androidManifast.xml
<application
        …
…   
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  – add the line
        >

app.component.ts


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RazorpayService } from './razorpay.service';
import { Checkout } from 'capacitor-razorpay';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {


 constructor(
  private _rzPay : RazorpayService
 ){}


Pay(){
  // this._rzPay.payWithrezorpay()
  this.payWithrezorpay()
}


async payWithrezorpay() {


  const options = {
    key: 'here your key',
    amount: '100',
    description: 'Turning Brain',
    image: 'https://turningbrain.in/website/assets/images/logo.png',
    // order_id: 'order_Cp10EhSaf7wLbS',
    currency: 'INR',
    name: 'Akhilesh Kumar',
    prefill: {
      email: 'tech.kr.akhi@gmail.com',
      contact: '62025727…'
    },
    theme: {
      color: '#3399cc'
    }
  }


  try {
    let data = (await Checkout.open(options));
    console.log(data.response + "AcmeCorp");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {


  }
}




}

Html –
<h1>hello</h1>


<button (click)="Pay()">pay</button>






.servies.ts

 createOrderLocal(amount: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/razorpay/order`, { amount });
  }


  verifyOrderLocal(order_id: string, payment_id: string, razorpay_signature: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/verifyOrder`, { order_id, payment_id }, {
      headers: {
        'x-razorpay-signature': razorpay_signature
      }
    });
  }




app.component.ts



  verifyPaymentLocal(data:any) {
    const order_id = data.razorpay_order_id;
    const payment_id = data.razorpay_payment_id;
    const razorpay_signature = data.razorpay_signature;


    this.razorpayService.verifyOrderLocal(order_id, payment_id, razorpay_signature)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.